# Repository Pattern With STE

Tags: entity-framework-4

i would like to develop an n-tier application. where i want to introduce entity framework with Repository, specification and Unit-of-work pattern within DAL layer. and domain object should be exposed as Self Tracking entities and there is thin WCF wrapper layer on top of business components.

please give me an example.

Thanks

Kawsar

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generic class that is base of your data service:

```
class BaseDataService<T>  where T : IYourModel or EntityObject
```

This class implement common action like Save(), GetItem(), Delete(),Get...

Now you can for Entities of your domain create a class that inherit from this base class:

```
class FooDataService:BaseDataService<Foo>
```